# do not allow to change ip address from inside a kvm guest

Tags: static, ip, acl, virtualization, kvm

At the moment, a customer having a virtual machine on kvm can simply change his own ip address or add another one and probably cause an ip address conflict.

How can I prevent that a user can change the ip address of his virtual machine?
I read about using ebtables over the bridged network on the host.

Isn't there something like an ACL feature or defining it directly in the guests XML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. Libvirt provides a feature called `nwfilter` which allows you to setup filters. There are also some example filters. They exactly do what I wanted. See [this link](https://github.com/wiedi/libvirt/tree/master/examples/xml/nwfilter).

I have downloaded them directly from github and defined with `virsh nwfilter-define <file.xml>`